# Integration by parts and gamma functions

Tags: integration

I am working through something to deepen my understanding and I am not sure of this step.

Getting from here
$$=\int^\infty_y \frac{e^{-z} z^{n+v-1}}{\Gamma(n+\nu)} \int^\infty_y \frac{e^{-k} k^{n}}{\Gamma(n+1)}dK$$
to here
$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty g(n+v,z)G(n+1,y)$$

Comment: Do you mean the uppercase gamma, i.e. $\Gamma$? If so, it's just \Gamma instead of \gamma.

Comment: thanks for that tip. Do you have any idea how to get form one step to the other?Thanks